# How to delete all empty links to files from DB and all redundant files

Tags: c#, file, entity-framework-core

I am building web app, which can store images. My DB stores paths to this images and all of them are stored in specific directory. How can I delete all files from download folder, which do not exist in DB, and all DB records, which have empty links?

For example, I have 3 files: `File1.jpg`, `File2.jpg`, `File3.jpg`.
My DB stores only `File1.jpg` and `File2.jpg`. For some reasons `File1.jpg` was deleted from directory but it's records still remain in DB. What is the best way to delete `File3.jpg` from folder(as it is not stored in DB) and `File1.jpg` from DB(as it does not exist in folder)?

I have written a method to delete files, which are not stored in DB:

```
    public async Task DeleteNonExistingImagesInFolder(string imagesDirectory)
    {
        var images = _unitOfWork.Images.AsQueryable();
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(imagesDirectory);
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles();
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (var file in Files)
            {
                if (!images.Where(i => i.Path == file.FullName).Any())
                    file.Delete();
            }
        });
    }
```

I have done the same thing for DB records:

```
    public async Task DeleteNonExistingImagesInDB(string imagesDirectory)
    {
        var images = _unitOfWork.Images.AsQueryable();
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(imagesDirectory);
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles();
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                if (!Files.Where(f => f.FullName == image.Path).Any())
                    _unitOfWork.Images.Remove(image.Id);
            }
        });
    }
```

But maybe there is a faster approach.

Comment: "the best way" is very subjective and depends on the rest of your infrastructure. What specifically have you tried?

Comment: Yeah there really is no "best" way for dealing with this. Going off of nothing, I would check to make sure a file actually exists when you get it back in a query. If it doesn't, delete it from the table. It would be better if you did this as only an exception case and properly locked down your file system so stuff like this cant happen.

Comment: @mxmissile, "the best way" i mean with less code and as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is pretty efficient and is done in a short bit of code. This just detects the changes you want from 2 collections and is a working example. See the end of the answer for some hints on what you will need to change for your implementation.

```
IEnumerable<string> files = new List<string> { "file1.txt", "file4.txt" };
IEnumerable<string> dbFiles = new List<string> { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt" };

IEnumerable<string> addsToFileSystem = files.Except(dbFiles);
IEnumerable<string> addsToDb = dbFiles.Except(files);

foreach (string file in addsToFileSystem) {
    Console.WriteLine($"delete {file} from file system");
}
foreach (string file in addsToDb) {
    Console.WriteLine($"delete {file} from db");
}
```

Output:

> delete file4.txt from file system
>
> delete file2.txt from db
>
> delete file3.txt from db

```
// get collection of files from "my files" directory and select just the file name
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("my files").Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x))
// replace with selecting the file names from your database
IEnumerable<string> dbFiles = _unitOfWork.Images.Select(x => x..FileName);

IEnumerable<string> addsToFileSystem = files.Except(dbFiles);
IEnumerable<string> addsToDb = dbFiles.Except(files);

foreach (string file in addsToFileSystem) {
    // remove from file system
}
foreach (string file in addsToDb) {
    // remove from db
}
```